# Bootstrap styling for input inside a label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to have a `input` or a `textarea` inside a `label` and be displayed inline in my form which is styled using Bootstrap 3. The following code is just a sample and my original code is different and more complex. I want to make sure that they look consistent with the remaining elements in the form.

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/Q2ua8PIq4z)

[image]

I want the `label`, `input` and `textarea` to look consistent with the Bootstrap form styling and have tried adding `control-label` and `form-control` classes to get the bootstrap styling but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

How to make the input `answer1` and textarea `answer2` have the Bootstrap styling like the `Name` and `Id` in the same form and also be inline with the labels surrounding them?

**Code**

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal padding-md" id="form1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3" for="sName">Name</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-9"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Name of the student."></span>
                <input type="text" id="sName" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3" for="sId">Id</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Id of the student."></span>
                <input type="text" id="sId" name="Id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1" for="answer1">1.</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-11"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Answer for first question."></span>
                <div class="inline">[<div class="sname">Student</div>'s answer: "<input type="text" id="answer1" name="Answer1" placeholder="Enter Answer">"]</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1" for="answer2">2.</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-11"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Answer for second question."></span>
              <div class="inline">[<div class="sname">Student</div>'s answer: "<textarea id="answer2" name="Answer2" placeholder="Enter Answer"></textarea>"]</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitAnswers">Submit Answers</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#sName').on('input', function() {
   $('.sname').html($('#sName').val()?$('#sName').val():"Student");
});
```

CSS

```
.help {
  position:absolute;
  right:-5px;
  top:8px;
}

.inline {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
 }

.sname {
    display:inline;
}

.padding-md {
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5r1731wx/1/ ??

Comment: Can you please add bootstrap libraries to the fiddle so that I can see how it looks with bootstrap styling?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5r1731wx/5/

Comment: @RachelGallen I have worked on it to improve it http://jsfiddle.net/5r1731wx/6/ but I still need `"]` in the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544092/bootstrap-styling-for-input-inside-a-label#comment51048044_31544092) and after some reading about [`display:table`](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero) I have found a solution by using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. This solution is very close to what I want except that I don't want the width of `sname1` and `sname2` to be a fixed value. It should ideally be adjusting based on the width of the name entered in `sName`. I will be using this solution till someone posts a better solution.

Solution:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5r1731wx/7/)

```js
$('#sName').on('input', function () {
    $('.sname').html($('#sName').val() ? $('#sName').val() : "Student");
});
```

```css
.help {
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:8px;
}
.inline {
    display:table;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
}
.sname2, .tail2 {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.sname {
    display:inline;
}
.sname1, .sname2 {
    width:150px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:table-cell;
}
.padding-md {
    padding: 25px;
}
.inline > .form-control {
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.tail1, .tail2 {
    padding-left:10px;
    width: 30px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal padding-md" id="form1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3" for="sName">Name</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-9"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Name of the student."></span>
                <input type="text" id="sName" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3" for="sId">Id</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Id of the student."></span>
                <input type="text" id="sId" name="Id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Id" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" for="answer1">1.</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Answer for first question."></span>
                <div class="inline">
                    <div class="sname1">[<div class="sname">Student</div>'s answer: "</div>
                    <input type="text" id="answer1" class="form-control" name="Answer1" placeholder="Enter Answer" />
                    <div class="tail1">" ]</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" for="answer2">2.</label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11"> <span class="help glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Answer for second question."></span>
                <div class="inline">
                    <div class="sname2">[<div class="sname">Student</div>'s answer: "</div>
                    <textarea id="answer2" class="form-control" name="Answer2" placeholder="Enter Answer"></textarea>
                    <div class="tail2">" ]</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitAnswers">Submit Answers</button>
    </div>
</form>
```